# Is there a list of microsoft excel functions ordered by computational cost?

Tags: excel

I am developing a tool in Excel but the formulas as proving to be extremely computationally intensive and updating the workbook is very slow.

I am wondering if I can use a combination of simpler / cheaper functions to achieve the same thing.

Is there any data around which functions are expensive/cheap?

I am using FILTER() extensively right now (1000's of cells running multiple filters per cell)

Previously I was using some COUNTIFS() but this had some problems working with range cell references.

Here's an example cell:

```
=COUNT(MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table[col], (Table[col]=$A48)*(Table[col]=$B$46) * (IF($B$9="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$9,0))))*(IF($B$10="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$10:$D$10,0))))*(IF($B$11="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$11:$C$11,0))))*(IF($B$12="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$12:$D$12,0))))*(IF($B$13="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$13:$D$13,0))))*(IF($B$14="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table[col],$B$14,0))))   )),Table[col],0))
```

Comment: If you find yourself asking these kinds of questions it *may* be time to move your data into an actual database system with actual support for queries -- if you want to keep things in Excel, look at Power Query, which uses an Analysis Services DB in the background. Certainly this kind of overview, even if someone bothered to make it, would not be stable across Excel versions, and would also depend quite heavily on the actual data in your workbook (as in, finding an item at the beginning of a list is faster than searching all cells to find nothing).

Comment: have you tried uing python and the openpyxl module to do the calculations and then output back into excel?

Comment: @NeoTheNerd I'm actually generating the formulas using openpyxl but the end result needs to be an excel work book some of the cells referenced are filter values to be able to filter directly in the excel file, if I pre compute the workbook values in python then I can't do that bit. The best solution I can see so far is to split the sheet into multiple sheets and calculate each individually.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm building the files using openpyxl  - do you know of any resources for techniques with power query + openpyxl?

Comment: Pretty sure Power Query is not reachable in any way through openpyxl. It's hard to tell from the one formula you posted, but I would look into fundamentally rethinking the current approach -- it looks as if you're essentially building a database in Excel, which is a great way of ending up with something that's slow and unmaintainable. The fact that Excel may be the tool of choice for presenting the data and allowing end-user filtering doesn't necessarily mean all data processing needs to happen there too. Consider tools like Power BI (essentially Power Query's successor) or SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

The computational cost can vary on which version of Excel you are using.

In the documentation you can read that:

> A sample test on copy/pasting 22,000 rows filtered from 44,000 rows
> showed a dramatic improvement:
>
> - For a table, the time went from 39 seconds in Excel 2013 and 18
>   seconds in Excel 2010 to 2 seconds in Excel 2016.
> - For a range, the
>   time went from 30 seconds in Excel 2013 and 13 seconds in Excel 2010
>   to instantaneous in Excel 2016.

[Filtering, sorting, and copy/pasting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements#filtering-sorting-and-copypasting)

You can find Excel performance tips for optimizing here:

[Excel performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#optimize-references-and-links)